# How do I use a "contains" operation as restful contextual filter for text fields

Tags: views, services, 8

I'm trying to create a restful view which takes a string as input, search specific content-type titles for similar nodes and return them as result.

The problem is I can't figure out how to configure the contextual operation to act as *contains*.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in a contextual filter, do this in a regular filter & you'll need to programmatically pass the value to the regular filter.

Comment: @NoSssweat Can you guide me how to "programmatically pass the value to the regular filter" in drupal 8? Is there any replacement for hook_views_pre_build ?

Comment: When you expose a filter, you can set an argument key to use as input to this exposed filter.  E.g. foo?search=xxx,  Given your requirements, you might want to either use the SearchAPI and it's views structure or code your own rest handler.  The SearchAPI lets you easily set up full text searches and manage results order based on boosts (e.g. words found in titles are more important).  The DB backend works well in D8 so you don't need Solr.

Comment: @CG Monroe thanks, solution helped, plz add it as an answer so I can accept and assign bounty to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you expose a filter, you can set a filter identifier.  This can be used to set the filter value via the URL, E.g.:  /search?keywords=foo or  /search?keyworks=foo+bar.

Note that if you need to hide this filter in a user view, you can do that with CSS or the Views Block View Filter module which allows you to move exposed filters to separate blocks that don't need to be placed on a user page.  Not part of your specs.. but nice to know if you need REST and user pages.

Also, given your requirements, you might want to consider either using the Search API module with it's views structure or code your own rest handler.

The Search API module will lets you easily set up full text searches and manage results order based on boosts, e.g. words found in titles are more important. The DB backend works well in D8, so you don't need Solr server for this.  (Though Solr has a lot of neat features).

Coding your own shouldn't be too hard with the D8 rest implementation.  You can then do any query variations you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rest view as per the image and access the results by this link
YOUR-WEBSITE.COM/api/v1/schools?name=COLLEGE_NAME

[image]